# Wrong assignment of matrix_world

Tags: python, transforms, rigidbody

I try to transform the camera by changing its "matrix_world", however, as shown in the figure, when I assign a matrix to it, the rotation part is transposed and the translation part is changed to zero.

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you cut and paste as text the python statements you entered in the console?  They don't appear in your blend file.

Comment: FWIW, I think you need to use `mathutils.Matrix` in your assignment rather than `np.array`.  When I do that I get the correct result.

Comment: Thank you for your attention @MartyFouts. It is figured out that, we should not assign an np.array to matrix_word. By using mathutils.Matrix, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

It is figured out that, we should not assign an np.array to "matrix_world". By using mathutils.Matrix, it works fine.